# How do I keep the iPhone screen from going dark when I take pictures outdoors?

Tags: iphone, screen, camera

I am using an iPhone 13 Pro to take pictures. I take a lot of pictures. When I take pictures outside for any duration of time the screen goes dark. This obviously makes it very difficult to see the screen and take effective pictures.

I have turned off Auto-Brightness in Display & Text Size and it doesn't make a difference.

What can I do to prevent the screen from going dark?

Comment: Am I right to assume 'outside' == 'out in the sun on a warm day' ?

Comment: That is correct outside in the sun on a warm or hot day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments, this is because it's out in the sun on a hot sunny day.

The answer is, keep it out of the sun.
It's a protection mechanism to stop it overheating. It will brighten again when it cools.

Comment: Alas, it may be the correct answer, but that is a serious limitation.

Comment: All electronic devices have an operating temperature tolerance - a computer has a fan to help, a phone doesn't. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201678

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.